# Dimensions plugin for Jenkins load any build artifacts to dimensions set request id

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, serena

In my Jenkins build job I pull java code from Gitlab and build on Jenkins using Ant build script (build.xml). A .zip file outcome of the build.

I am trying to upload build artifacts (zip file) to Dimensions CM using Dimensions plugin for Jenkins using 'load any build artifacts to dimensions' as a post build action. Dimension is rejecting the artifact due to lack of the request id for it attach this artifact in Dimensions.

The [plugin documentation](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Dimensions+Plugin) says to "If you wish to specify a request to save these changes against, then you should set a project default request using SCWS or use DM_TARGET_REQUEST"

I am getting this error:

> START =======
>  Started by user Ahmad, Ershad
>  [EnvInject] -
>   Loading node environment variables.
>  Building on master in
>   workspace /opt/wss/stg/jenkins/DimensionsUpload1
>  [DIMENSIONS]
>   Calculating changes for directory
>   'DM_TARGET_REQUEST=PCMTPROJPROJ_SMR_82'...
>  [DimensionsUpload1] $
>   /bin/sh -xe
>   /opt/wss/stg/apache-tomcat-6.0.43/temp/hudson7507543782532160733.sh
>   + cd /opt/wss/stg/jenkins/DimensionsUpload1
>   + ls -ltr
>  total 138484
>   -rw-r-----. 1 webdev webdev 141800254 Feb 16 08:11 BuildArtifact.1.0.zip
>  [DIMENSIONS] Running checkin on
>   master...
>  [DIMENSIONS] Running build in
>   '/opt/wss/stg/jenkins/DimensionsUpload1'...
>  [DIMENSIONS] Scanning
>   workspace for files to be saved into Dimensions...
>  [DIMENSIONS]
>   Running Ant pattern scanner...
>  [DIMENSIONS] Found 1 file(s) to
>   check in...
>  [DIMENSIONS] Loading files into Dimensions project
>   "PCMTPROJ:RELSTREAM"...
>  FATAL: Unable to run checkin callout
>   (DimensionsRuntimeException: Upload files (DimensionsRuntimeException:
>   Dimensions command 'UPLOAD 
>   /USER_FILELIST="/opt/wss/stg/apache-tomcat-6.0.43/temp/dmCm15188000765706781907912904279764.tmp"
>   /WORKSET="PCMTPROJ:RELSTREAM" /COMMENT="Build artifacts delivered by
>   Jenkins for job 'DEVOPS_PCMTPROJ_DmUpload' - build 68"
>   /USER_DIRECTORY="/opt/wss/stg/jenkins/DimensionsUpload1"' failed
>   (DimensionsRuntimeException: Using Project 'PCMTPROJ:RELSTREAM'. Using
>   '/opt/wss/stg/jenkins/DimensionsUpload1/' as the Project work
>   area.
>  Scanning repository: 0.00 sec
>  Scanning local work
>   area: 0.00 sec
>  Creating new item revision for
>   '/opt/wss/stg/jenkins/DimensionsUpload1/BuildArtifact.1.0.zip'
>   **COR0005162E Error: To create a new Item revision of type PROD_CODE you must specify a valid request
>  COR0006384E Error: Failed to
>   create Item for
>   '/opt/wss/stg/jenkins/DimensionsUpload1/BuildArtifact.1.0.zip'**
>
>   Warning: There were errors while uploading files from the specified
>   network node. Please check the upload log.
>  Updating files: 2.57
>   sec
>  Uploading Project: 2.58 sec
>  )))
>  Build step 'Load
>   any build artifacts into the Dimensions repository' changed build
>   result to FAILURE
>  Build step 'Load any build artifacts into the
>   Dimensions repository' marked build as failure
>  Finished:
>   FAILURE
>   =======END

I have tried using the export command in shell but it doesn't work:

```
cd /opt/wss/stg/jenkins/DimensionsUpload1
ls -ltr
export  $ITEM_TYPE PROD_CODE
export $DM_TARGET_REQUEST PCM_SMR_82
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this using the below option 
Click on configure in your build job 
[Check box] This build is parameterized (see pic below)

[image]